# Why is the REST API of Android able to connect to a GAE web application directly?

Tags: android, restlet

I have been trying to find a way to implement a RESTful web service and then consume this service from an Android REST client. The reason is that Android intrinsically only supports consuming a RESTful web service.

However, when I came across this [web site](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1462), I got totally confused! The author is using the `org.apache.http.client` API to connect to a web application built by Google App Engine. I tested it and it worked!

But, to my understanding, isn't Google App Engine a RPC-styled web service? Doesn't it need external libraries such as Restlet to convert to a RESTful web service? Why is the REST API of Android able to connect to a GAE web application directly?

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine is just an web app server. As long as a framework only uses classes in GAE's [JRE White List](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) then it should be usable on the server. This includes Spring mVC, Jersey, Restlet and other tools on this [list](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava). For one of my Android apps I use a GAE server to run RESTful Web Services with Spring MVC and it works great.

Comment: Thank you Robby, I've got ur idea. But again, the example I mentioned was just using the simplest implementation of GAE, a java servlet. Why is an Android application still able to access that? I got the point just now, org.apache.http.client is in fact a raw http client that makes http call, then what's the meaning of that Android only intrinsically supports RESTful web service? With the http client I can always access a http service regardless of whether it's RPC or RESTful. Hence, what's the point here?

Comment: Since the Android SDK includes HttpClient/java.net classes you can access any server over http. The type of server doesn't matter. When it comes down to it you are just requesting data. The way they data is sent to your client doesn't matter. Android has nothing to do with REST, REST is just an architectural style.

Comment: I understand the fact REST is just an architecture style. But, I have always seen people discussing about the fact that android sdk doesn't come with a SOAP API but a REST API, and if you wanna use SOAP, you gotta go for something like "KSOAP2". I think it's clear that HttpClient/java.net has nothing to do with REST. Then what's the api are they referring to?

Comment: Then those people are wrong. Android comes with an HttpClient that lets it perform Http Requests. REST requests are over HTTP, SOAP requests are over HTTP. There is nothing stopping you from making a SOAP request with HttpClient. You just have to do all the xml parsing and writing yourself. That's what the SOAP apis help with.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much for your help!! It's the most meaningful answer I've got so far. BTW, your blog looks nice!